# C++ MIDL2025: Expecting a type specification near ""

Tags: c++, arrays, atl

I want my IDL file to implement a function that returns String array, so I tried it like:

```
[id(2)] HRESULT GReport_Person1([out, retval] std::vector<std::string> *Result);
[id(3)] HRESULT GReport_Person2([out, retval] std::vector<BSTR> *Result);
```

But this generates the error:

> MIDL2025   syntax error : expecting a type specification near "std"

But I want it to return this array or a `std::vector<BSTR>` anyway, please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the std containers in MIDL and COM in such a way.

Either you have to use pointers and arrays as memory block in COM. So you can use [MIDL arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367081(v=vs.85).aspx). Here are some [different types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373963(v=vs.85).aspx) of arrays in [MIDL syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366731(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you want to use the interface in automation you have to use VARIANT elements containing a SafeArray. Standard Automation with IDispatch (VBScript) only supports SafeArrays of VARIANTS again. But you are free to use SafeArrays of BSTR too.

Comment: Thank you! Nice answer. :-)